# Is there any way to open a file which is already saved locally by clicking a URL in a browser?

Tags: internet, redirection, url

I want to be able to do the following:

I will click a URL `www.xxxxxxxx.com/xx/x.doc` but the browser will open a local instance of the file at `C:/x2.doc`.

Can this be done?

Comment: do you have access to the server hosting www.xxxxxxxx.com? if so you could i guess redirect to something like `file:///C:/x2.doc`...

Comment: The quick answer is no. If you click on a URL, the browser will open that URL. If you want to open the local version, type `file:///c:/x2.doc` in the browser bar

Comment: @pataluc - no, that really isn't easily doable...

Comment: @MaddDMo you sure? i can't see why a php redirect `<?php header('Location: file:///C:/x2.doc'); ?>` or an Apache redirect won't work...

Comment: @pataluc OK, my bad, I suppose that's possible, but it would only work for someone that already **had** the local file. But still, I get the impression the OP doesn't have access to the server...

Comment: i fully agree...

Answer (score 1):

i was able to get it to work on IE8 with the following Apache conf: (my test with FF21.0 failed)

```
Redirect /xx/x.doc file:///C:/x2.doc
```

but i don't very much like that solution, it's not very classy.